# Переменные в Java

Tags: java, переменные

Я понимаю что вопрос из разряда гугл в помощь, но я не могу это найти.
Вопрос: Допустим есть два класса Person и Block. У них одинаковые переменные

private x,
private y.

Как сделать общий класс с переменными, так чтобы у наследовавшись от него переменные были private.

Comment: почитайте про модификаторы доступа. private  означает, что поле видно только в пределах класса. хотите к нему обратиться  - гетеры и сетеры в помощь. хотите его получить в классах наследниках - есть protected.

Comment: Я протестировал свой код -  он не правельный. Потому что я могу из третьего класса обратиться напрямую к х. Мне надо чтобы переменные были приватные. и ииз третьего класса можно было обратиться только через геттер

Comment: Ну тогда никак.

Comment: Внесите все требования в вопрос (кнопка «править»), добавьте код и объясните как можно подробнее.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете оставить `private` переменные в суперкласе, но гетеры/сетеры сделать `protected` , чтобы они были доступны из подкласов.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A{
    protected int x;
}

public class B extends A{

    B(int x){
        this.x=x;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: лучше сделать конструктор в классе А, который будет устанавливать значение икса. А вызывать его через `super`

Comment: Я протестировал свой код -  он не правельный. Потому что я могу из третьего класса обратиться напрямую к х. Мне надо чтобы переменные были приватные. и ииз третьего класса можно было обратиться только через геттер

Comment: Тогда пиши на си++ вместо джавы.